# C# SAP Crystal Report Cannot Pass Main Report Parameters to Sub Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

It is working when I add subreport on my Main report however if I add parameters to my sub report and link it from my Main to Sub Report, SAP Crystal Report just stuck on loading **"Please Wait while the document is processing**".

These are my parameters on my Main Report which is the same parameters I use at my subreport, Take note that the parameters on my subreport is not in use in my stored procedure query yet I'm just trying to pass the parameters first, I even try reAdding the subreport from scratch,

```
            @SortType     Varchar(50),
            @StartDate    DATETIME,
            @EndDate      DATETIME,
            @DeptGroup    Varchar(50),
            @DateType     Varchar(50)
```

These steps I did,

1. I add the same exact parameters from Main Report to Subreport Stored Procedure
2. Verified Database to show the parameters from Sub Report
3. Adding Subreport to Main Report.
4. Changed SubReport Links

Tried testing one parameter

```
 USE [foo]
 GO
  /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_ReportShowMedia]    Script Date: 06/07/2016 08:28:45 ******/

  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[usp_ReportShowMedia] (                          
            @SortType     Varchar(50)
        )
        AS
    BEGIN
             select * from users
    END
```

Comment: So I am assuming, if you remove sub report parameters you can load the report? Can you add sub report parameters one by one, link them and then run the report to see which param is causing problem

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response I added my stored procedure in my question, the parameters on my subreport is not used yet in my query so I think adding one by one would not help?

Comment: btw On my Main Report I'm using Dynamic SQL, does it affect on how to link reports?

Comment: Can you update your question with CR version

Comment: What do you mean CR Version?
I already changed my Main Report Stored Procedure (not Dynamic Sql) still the same thing.. 

and yes if I remove sub report parameters the report is fine.

Comment: When Viewing in Main Report Preview it's working  but when running the report itself it doesn't :( just stuck on please wait while the document is processing but when I check task manager It's still responding.

Comment: how you running the report via code? yes, then debug and check the parameter will pass to main report as well as sub-report.

Comment: I am using  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortType", this.SortType); to the Main Report, which works. Isn't when you link stored value parameters for 
       example'@StartDate = @StartDate2 it will automatically get the value of main report as well?

Comment: how can you debug if parameters will pass to subreport? @Ajay2707